# Responsive design posts

Tags: css

I am trying to set up posts with pictures. I already write a code where the position of pictures is correct but only in the mobiles. Is there any CSS command which can I use?

```css
.image1{
  height: 100px;
  weight: 100px;
}
.image2{
  height: 100px;
  weight: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 135px;
}
```

I already use this

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 601px) and (max-device-width: 768px)
```

but it does not work out.

And of course, I have set up on my header

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any advice how can I set up positioning of pictures of PCs?

Comment: Pure CSS/HTML questions are better asked at stackoverflow, this isn't a WordPress question

Answer (score 1):

use percentages `%` rather than PX so it will take the percentage in any device and you can control this percentage in any media query and it will save you a lot.
another tip you can use aspect ratio on images to be fit in any devices and use property called `object-fit` it will help you to prevent images being squeezing .